# Render process Browser Window not working in Electronjs

Tags: javascript, electron

I am creating simple eletronjs app. I need if i click button want show admin.html file new window. But I added correct code inside admin.js file but error this displayed **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BrowserWindow')** I referred more reference but could not solve this issue. could you please solve this issue.

main.js

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true
    }
  })
    
  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <button id="test">Test</button>
    <script>
      require('./admin.js')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

admin.js

```js
const BrowserWindow = require('electron').remote.BrowserWindow;
const path = require('path')
const url = require('url');

const newbtn = document.getElementById('test');
newbtn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  let window1 = new BrowserWindow();
  window1.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'admin.html'),
    protocal: 'file',
    slashes: true
  }));
});
```

admin.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'">
    <link href="assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is admin window</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're making this way more complicated than it is: in index.html, use `<script src="admin.js"></script>` and in admin.js remove the three require lines at the top, then do only this inside the click handler: `location = "admin.html";` (you should probably rename admin.js to index.js, too)

Comment: Not working , My requirement when button click show window. could you update please

Comment: It works fine for me. Check the console of the dev tools in the electron / chrome window for error messages. edit: wait: in a new window? Have you tried `window.open('admin.html')`?

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/window-open

Comment: Could you please update my code.

Comment: great, feel free to remove the question yourself